# Repair Ubuntu broken files under live Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mount, live-usb, files

My installed Ubuntu 14.04 goes to a black screen after the splash screen and gets stuck there.

I know where the problem is; I deleted a file, `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml`, from `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` in my last session. Now I want to repair that and copy/move the original file into there until the problem is resolved but unfortunately I can't do this.

I've done these steps:

1. Boot from the live USB.
2. Mount my root partition: (it's on `/dev/sda6`)

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
   ```
3. Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

   ```
   for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
   ```
4. `chroot` into my Ubuntu install:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```

Now I am in my Ubuntu root partition, original file copied in Live Ubuntu home folder (`/home/ubunut/original_File_here`), and destination is `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` in mounted partition.

I tried the commands below but I get an error.

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo mv 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml' '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/'
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
mv: cannot stat 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml': No such file or directory
```

And

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo mv 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml' '/dev/sda6/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/'
sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu
mv: failed to access '/dev/sda6/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/': Not a directory
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to chroot first, you can just mount your `/` and then copy the file over. Make sure the owner UID / GID are the same.

Open terminal and run this command:

```
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml /mnt/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

assuming `/mnt` is where you mounted your original `/`.